# windows phone 8 connecting to windows 7 through microsoft.smartphone.connectivity DLL

Tags: windows-phone-8, windows-7-x64

I connected the windows phone 8 to windows 8 machine through usb via `microsoft smart phone connectivity v4.0_11.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a dll`. Its working fine.

but i tried the same with windows 7 machine its not working ( As there are no dlls on windwos 7) I copied the dll's from windows 8 machine to windows 7 machine but now its giving me the error for class ID is not registeerd. I tried to register the dll's but no lick.

I tried to use older version of connectivity dll ( `v4.0_10.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a`) then it detects only windows phone 7 so it is not detecting my windows phone 8 apps.

Please suggest.

Answer (score 0):

This will probably never work as you're trying to install bits of the WP8 SDK piecemeal into Windows 7, which is not supported.

For WP8 apps you need Windows 8 OS.